# How can i make my python program work in background

Tags: python, background

I've made a program that needs to work in the background even if i close it.

I couldn't find a way to do it, open to any suggestions.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Search in your browser for "Python background program"

Answer (score -1):

As a matter of fact , i am not interested into keep running program after closing tab in Windows OS, so i will explain the solution in Linux , Ubuntu

you can try such things like

```
nohup filename &
```

or something Like

```
nohup filename > /dev/null
```

Another key word that may help you to find out your solution is `deamon` that [this link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/daemon.7.html#:%7E:text=A%20daemon%20is%20a%20service,scheme%20originating%20in%20SysV%20Unix.) will explain it well.